# Список элементов bitrix отображается с кривой версткой

Tags: битрикс, crm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Интерфейс списка элементов отображается как на картинке. Кнопки действий, редактирование, удаление не работают. Если отмечать флажки свойств то ничего не происходит, изменения не сохраняются. Кнопка применить тоже не работает. Переустанавливал дистрибутив, не помогло.
.

Comment: Попробуйте [это](https://qna.habr.com/q/700449)

Comment: В браузере в режиме инкогнито то же самое? Кэш чистили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разворачивали на локальном сервере? Если да, то это бесполезно, у кого то дистрибутив встает без проблем, у кого то надо с бубнами танцевать.
Мое предположение, что просто что-то не догрузилось.
Если были ошибки модулей и вы их пропускали, модуль мог установиться не корректно.

У меня например вообще битрикс на локальном сервере отказывается вставать. Месяц бьюсь,ни одной похожей проблемы не нашел.

Так что тут поможет только удача.

А так, если есть где то на сервере развернутый, то сверяйте ваши файлы с файлами в ядре.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).